# Displacement works in viewport but not in render (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, displacement, volumetrics

My problem is that my noise displacement map is working well in the viewport (Cycles rendered mode) but when I f12 render the image, the displacement just disappears. What am I doing wrong?
[image] [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTPuA.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Just a blind guess - perhaps Subdivision Modifier disabled for renders?

Comment: The modifier is enabled for render.